# Getting DLLNotFoundException while running MathType SDK Dotnet samples

Tags: mathtype

I have installed MathType 6.9 for windows and I am trying run Dotnet sample MTSDKTestApplication, getting failed with "MT6" Dll not found exception. Basically here application is compiling successfully but in runtime clicking MTApiConnect button I am getting below exception

"Unable to load DLL 'MT6.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

One more thing can I Integrate MathType editor with Dotnet Desktop application(WPF) or Web (ASP.Net) for adding, editing math equations. My requirement is when user trying to enter math equation I want to show this mathtype editor and While editing any equation, equation should export to math type editor.

Thanks,
Srikanth

Answer (score 0):

the MT6.dll was a C++ library, you should copy it from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MathType\System\MT6.dll" to your project path or add reference path.